# SQL : join if not in table or select only one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have four tables : one of users, one of profiles (users profiles), one of relations between profile and content and one of content. That content table could have no entry, single or multiple entry for a user profile.

I would like to get all the users who have no entry in the content table or if they have multiple entries, get only one.

Here is my current SQL :

```
SELECT
users.uid AS uid,
profile.id AS profile_id,
content.id AS content_id
FROM 
users users_data
LEFT JOIN profile profile_data ON users_data.id = profile_data.uid
LEFT JOIN content_for_profile content_profile ON profile_data.id = content_profile.pid
LEFT JOIN content content_data ON content_for_profile.content_id = content_data.id
JOIN (
SELECT content_data_join.id, content_data_join.uid
FROM content content_data_join
GROUP BY content_data_join.uid
) content_data_join ON content_for_profile.content_id=content_data_join.id
GROUP BY uid, profile_id, content_id
ORDER BY profile.created DESC
```

I tried to add the simple JOIN to get only one result from the content table and it works. But with that, i don't get users with no entry in the content table.

I've been stuck for hours and try so many things ... Thanks in advance for your help !

EDIT :

user example

```
id
8
9
10
```

profile example :

```
id uid
2000 8
2001 9
2002 10
```

content_for_profile example :

```
id pid content_id
1 2000 100
2 2001 101
3 2001 102
```

content example :

```
id uid
100 8
101 9
102 9
```

expected result :

```
uid profile_id content_id
8 2000 100
9 2001 101
10 2002 NULL
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve first.

Comment: Ok i'm creating some fake data and will edit my post soon !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for get the user without entry in content table you can use where condition for null

```
    SELECT
    users.uid AS uid,
    profile.id AS profile_id,
    content.id AS content_id
    FROM 
    users users_data
    LEFT JOIN profile profile_data ON users_data.id = profile_data.uid
    LEFT JOIN content_for_profile content_profile ON profile_data.id = content_profile.pid
    LEFT JOIN content content_data ON content_for_profile.content_id = content_data.id

    where content_data.id is null  

    ORDER BY profile.created DESC
```

You should not use GROUP BY without aggreation function. this deprecated  is most db and is not allowed  in the most recent version of mysql

a
for get just one  entry for content value  the you can use an aggreation function eg min() ..max()

```
    SELECT
    users.uid AS uid,
    profile.id AS profile_id,
    min(content.id) AS content_id
    FROM 
    users users_data
    LEFT JOIN profile profile_data ON users_data.id = profile_data.uid
    LEFT JOIN content_for_profile content_profile ON profile_data.id = content_profile.pid
    LEFT JOIN content content_data ON content_for_profile.content_id = content_data.id

    GROUP BY users.uid ,profile.id 
    ORDER BY profile.created DESC
```

Comment: Would it not *also* be the case that the `JOIN` on the sub-query needs to be a `LEFT JOIN`?  *(As it is joining on to a table that itself has been `LEFT JOIN`ed?)*

Comment: I just tried the both, and the first one is returning no result. And the second one returning the exact same result as mine

Comment: @rob-art  then update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: @rob-art  answer  updated  removing  the (unuseful) join on subquery  ..

Comment: Great work like a charm ! Thank you. I'm not very good at SQL, do you have an explanation on this process ?

Comment: the subquery you have added  using join was  not useful  ..  just produce more rows repect what you really need ..  .. in my answer the first query retrive then row with null value in content table ..checking for null values ..the second  use  min(...) and group by for reduce the numbers of rows  return   selecting only the min(value) for the content result .. hope is clear